# How to deploy a ASP.NET MVC 4 website on IIS8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I want to deploy it on IIS 8. I read on the internet that it's possible to do that directly through VS 2010/2013 by creating a package and publish it but I want to deploy it with IIS manager. I tried to do it manually by doing these steps :

1. Right-Click on Sites (left panel in IIS Manager) > Add a web site.
2. Specifying the physical path of my project (I've put it on C:), giving a port number (here 3500) and giving a url name (for instance, www.abc.net (or .com)).
3. Clicking on OK and my web site appears in the left panel.

When I launch my website through Chrome, the browser says that he can't access http://www.abc.net:3500

What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to deploy my MVC website **without Visual Studio**?

EDIT : By following Imran's first link, it seems that I made a step ahead. However, instead of access the Index page of my app, that's what the browser displays :

[My project folder's list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AijwK.png)

Should I configure something in my RouteConfig? Here it is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AstellasSchedulerV2 {
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default", // Route name
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a deployment package using `Visual Studio` by going to **Build > Publish {project name}** and follow the wizard.

In `IIS` click on a site and there should be an option for **Import Application** under the **Deploy** menu. If you don't see this then you need to install the [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) module into `IIS`.

Alternatively, if you're still developing your solution you can configure `Visual Studio` to use your `IIS` installation by going to the project's **Properties > Web** and choose **Use Local IIS Web server**. When you run your application it will copy the build over to your default website automatically and run it from there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you do wrong. Check the logs. Set up a web.config that shows the error when you access the site locally and / or remotely for debugging purposes. Your question is like "I have a car. It does not work. What is wrong?".

Once you enable remote debugging in teh web.config you should see a proper error message.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx

tells that the settings are:

Change the customErrors mode attribute from "RemoteOnly" to "Off", and then save the file.

and then you should see more than a "Error 500". Making sense out of that is your job then ;)

Comment: I think I gave enough details... If not, what should I have mentionned ? Could you please have a look on my edited post? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below articles step by step

[IIS 8.0 Using ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45#TOC301258515)

and

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

**EDIT**

Publish your website code properly and then try below

1)Please check below configration in global.asax.

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

2)your route config should be

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "your default controller", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

3)Disabled Directory browsing in IIS 8.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still have some problems. Could you see my updated post? Thanks again !

Comment: Index action is your first page ? or  just copy paste which action should you want to default and then try

Comment: Yes, the Index action is the main page. What should I do now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: lets check EDIT part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my global.asax.cs and my RouteConfig are exactly the same as yours but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55426/discussion-between-imran-and-traffy).